# Operator == error coming in gridview rowbound event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am checking for checkbox values in GridView1_RowDataBound  event but getting error "operator can not be applied to operands of type string or bool"..

here is my code for the same...

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

            if (e.Row.Cells[i].ToString() == true)
            {
                cb.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cb.Checked = false;
            }
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cb);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me ..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (e.Row.Cells[i].ToString() == true)
{
    cb.Checked = true;
}
```

You're comparing the string value `Cells[i].ToString()` to the boolean value `true`.

If the cell contains a string value that represents true or false, you need to parse it to a boolean:

```
bool result;
if (Boolean.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out result))
{
    if (result)
    {
        ....
    }
}
else
{
    // Item is not a valid boolean - throw an exception or just default to false
}
```

Comment: againg getting error "The best overloaded method match for 'bool.TryParse(string, out bool)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @vikas Sorry, you still need the `.ToString()` on the cell value. See my updated post. Note that this assumes that the value of the cell can actually be converted to a boolean.